# Regarding how the kubernetes etcd runs the Raft consensus

Tags: kubernetes

When I was studying the Kubernetes architecture I noticed the truth that etcd runs Raft consensus protocol to maintain a reliable key-value store for all the information inside the Kubernetes cluster. I have studied Raft in depth when I was learning distributed system but here due to the lack of knowledge of Kubernetes I'm having some confusions about how Raft really comes into the game here:

Basically I have searched all the online resources that tried to explain the role of Raft here and right now my visualization about etcd here is that there are multiple nodes inside a single etcd, and when we talk about Raft here we are talking about Raft that runs inside all of these "etcd" nodes instead of all the master and worker nodes that we often talk about in Kubernetes, am I right?

If what I have said above is correct, then the whole point of this etcd should be fault tolerance in my opinion, but when we draw the architecture of Kubernetes etcd usually looks like a stand alone piece of database, I'm curious about in practice how and where these etcd nodes get deployed? They have to be deployed separately otherwise it is still a single point failure isn't it? And how many etcd nodes typically are there in one kubernetes cluster deployment?

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: Kubernetes does not really care how it's deployed: it's totally up to you or your deployment tools. As long as kubernetes API server can connect to it - you're good.

Comment: If I say: "treat ETCD as a distributed highly available database where kubernetes stores its data which may _sometimes_ run on the same nodes as kubernetes itself" - would it resolve your confusion?

Comment: If I understanding what you are trying to say here, you basically mean that Kubernetes often utilize the actual worker nodes as a construct of ETCD cluster, so the information in ETCD, at the end of day, can land at the actual nodes in our Kubernetes cluster, is that right?

Comment: "Kubernetes often utilize the actual worker nodes as a construct of ETCD cluster" --- I would not say that. ETCD runs on wherever the sysadmin decided them to run. In my clusters ETCD daemons run on every kubernetes master (and I deploy kubernetes with `kubeadm`). I'm not sure I ever seen ETCD to be self-hosted, unless those are some crazy experiments. What it means is that at most ETCD are  _static pods_, which are not scheduled and always run on the same machines.

Comment: Okay I guess the main reason I’m feeling confused here is probably because I just started studying Kubernetes yesterday, and I’m still trying to grasp all these terms and jargons in this system... So if in your case it runs on all the master node, wouldn’t that mean we have to have a certain amount of master nodes so that we can get a fault tolerant ETCD? But I assume we are also allowed to have only one master node right?

Comment: Number of master nodes and number of ETCD are tangential. For ETCD cluster to be healthy you need to have majority online. For kubernetes to be healthy you need at one master alive. Don't confuse yourself even further: treat ETCD as a database which kubernetes uses as a storage, and that database runs _somewhere_.

Comment: You are right, I probably shouldn’t dig too deep inside of it especially given I’m learning it for my interview lol... The reason that I’m really willing to know the things under the hood is because I have encountered something here which I have studied in university but only in an academic level, so I’m really eager here to understand how Raft comes to play a role here, and thanks for your answer here!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218792/discussion-between-zerkms-and-boooooo).

Comment: @Boooooo Does this conversation solves your issue? Would you like to post it as an answer for the overall clarity?

Answer (score 0):

This is a community wiki answer based on the conversation from the chat. Posting it for the clarity and to show answers for the OP's questions raised there. I do not take any reputation gains for it. Feel free to edit and expand it.

> - Kubernetes does not really care how it's deployed: it's totally up to you or your deployment tools. As long as kubernetes API server can
>   connect to it - you're good.
> - `Kubernetes often utilize the actual worker nodes as a construct of ETCD cluster?` - I would not say that. ETCD runs on wherever the
>   sysadmin decided them to run. In my clusters ETCD daemons run on every
>   kubernetes master (and I deploy kubernetes with kubeadm). What it
>   means is that at most ETCD are static pods, which are not scheduled
>   and always run on the same machines.
> - `So if in your case it runs on all the master node, wouldn’t that mean we have to have a certain amount of master nodes so that we can get a fault tolerant ETCD? But I assume we are also allowed to have only one master node right?` - Number of master nodes and number of
>   ETCD are tangential. For ETCD cluster to be healthy you need to have
>   majority online. For kubernetes to be healthy you need at one master
>   alive. Don't confuse yourself even further: treat ETCD as a database
>   which kubernetes uses as a storage, and that database runs somewhere.